# Why my bootstrap-datepicker does not have icon-calendar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to use [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

I have included the `datepicker.css` and `bootstrap-datepicker.js` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Then in my div, I did like this:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp2" data-date="15-07-2013" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
   <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="15-07-2013" readonly>
   <label class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></label>
</div>
```

Then at last, I did like this:

```
<script>

    $(function(){

      $('#dp2').datepicker();

      });
</script>
```

---

I can see the date picker, but without the **icon**.

[image]

I wish to have like:

[image]

**What I did wrong?**

---

**Edit**

My full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Date</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/readable/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="well">
        <h4>Date Picker</h4>
    <div class="input-append date" id="dp2" data-date="15-07-2013" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
      <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="15-07-2013">
      <label class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></label>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>

      $(function(){

      $('#dp1').datepicker();
      $('#dp2').datepicker();

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the glyphicons in the correct img folder?

Comment: @glosrob ehh...I guess not

Comment: @glosrob I added https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/img to my folder, still no icon-calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've put [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PmvG/) together which works using the following HTML:

```
<div class="input-append date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" id="dp3" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012"/>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" id="cal"></i></span>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#dp3').datepicker();
});
```

The difference being that `id="dp3"` is applied to the `input` tag and not the containing `div`. However, it seems that in your case it's related to *how* and *where* you're referencing your includes.

The [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PmvG/) above references the base files directly (from both CDN and author sites), so it's likely related to how you are referencing the location (relative or absolute) of the glyphicons/js/css files.

Without a direct link to your implementation or full code, it's hard to diagnose the problem further than this.

Comment: Hi, I tried your JSFiddle link, but still, I can't see that calendar icon. http://oi42.tinypic.com/2h39csi.jpg

Comment: @TimS I think the linked resources have changed; probably updating the libraries. I'll look at it and update if needed. It certainly worked when I answered it.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by using this: :)

```
<div class="input-append date" id="theDate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <form:input path="theDate" class="span2" size="130" readonly="true"/>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/....../datepicker.png"/></i></span>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.... :)

Comment: Please add an example of how it can be done to improve your answer.

Comment: Hi Szymon, this is an example:  
    <div class="input-append date" id="theDate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    
 <form:input path="theDate" class="span2" size="130" readonly="true"/>
     
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th">
  <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/....../datepicker.png"/></i>
     </span>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Because of markup changes for Bootstrap v2 and Bootstrap v3.
The sandbox demo helped me to find the correct markup:
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

```
<div class="input-append date">
<input type="text" class="span2">
    /* this next line should help you */
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

$('.input-append.date').datepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience using the "icon-calendar" so I just used the bootstrap glyphicon which comes with the bootstrap lib and it worked like a charm:

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
   <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly>
   <span class="add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an redundant `<span>`  tag: `<span class="add-on">` does not close

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <label>Date</label>
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="my-date-picker" id="foo" type="text" />
    <label for="foo" class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></label>
</div>
```

And one line of javaScript to complete your job...

```
$(".my-date-picker").datepicker();
```