# Why doesn't my calendar icon appear in a table cell?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, datepicker, font-awesome

I am using Bootstrap date picker in a table, but I'm not able to put date picker icon using `fas fa-calendar-alt` css class.

```
 <td>
     <input type="text" 
            id="expirydate{{$index}}"  
            class="form-control date-new date-only" 
            data-ng-init="onloadFun(this)"  
            ng-model="ven.expiryDate">

        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>  
</td>
```

I tried something like above but its not showing icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my bootstrap-datepicker does not have icon-calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664515/why-my-bootstrap-datepicker-does-not-have-icon-calendar)

Comment: maybe should be class="fa fa-calendar-alt" ?

Comment: What do you mean "not able to"? What markup appears in the document? Does that icon class exist in your version of the Font Awesome library?

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using to integrate the datepicker with the AngularJS framework? Which version of font-awesome? Use the Developer Console to inspect the element and diagnose the behavior. Create a [MInimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the positioning of your textbox. If it is overlaying the icon, it will not show (icon may be behind your input field). If this is the case, you can try making the icon absolute position and z-index greater than the textbox in CSS. Inspecting using the developer tools may also shed some light on your issue.